# How to create an Outlook 2010 search folder for messages from anyone in a specified address book?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, microsoft-outlook-2010

How would I create an Outlook 2010 search folder for messages from anyone in a specified address book?

Comment: did you ever find a solution?